# std::enable_if - how to use own function as template argument

Tags: c++, qt, templates, enable-if

I have class ModeSessions and 2 derived classes : ReadModeSessions and WriteModeSessions;
ModeSessions has a unique Mode type;
In Logic I collect in container every session with own unique type. 
But now I stuck on template method to return proper session by given mode.

```
#include <QVector>
#include <QSharedPointer>
namespace states {
    enum class Mode{ read1, read2, write1, write2};
    constexpr bool modeIsReadType(Mode m){ return (m == Mode::read1 || m == Mode::read2)? true: false;}
    constexpr bool modeIsWriteType(Mode m){ return (m == Mode::write1 || m == Mode::write2)? true: false;}
}

class ModeSession{
public:
    states::Mode type;
};
using namespace states;
class ReadModeSession: public ModeSession{
public:
    ReadModeSession(Mode m){ModeSession::type = m;}
};
class WriteModeSession : public ModeSession{
public:
    WriteModeSession(Mode m){ModeSession::type = m;}
};
class Logic
{
public:
    Logic(){
        allModeSessions << QSharedPointer<ReadModeSession>(new ReadModeSession(Mode::read1));
        allModeSessions << QSharedPointer<ReadModeSession>(new ReadModeSession(Mode::read2));
        allModeSessions << QSharedPointer<WriteModeSession>(new WriteModeSession(Mode::write1));
        allModeSessions << QSharedPointer<WriteModeSession>(new WriteModeSession(Mode::write2));
    }
    QVector<QSharedPointer<ModeSession>> allModeSessions;
    template<class Tm> QSharedPointer<ReadModeSession>
        getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsReadType(m), Tm>::type){
        for (QSharedPointer<ModeSession> ms: allModeSessions){
            if (ms->type == m) return ms.dynamicCast<ReadModeSession>();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
    template<class Tm> QSharedPointer<WriteModeSession>
        getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsWriteType(m), Tm>::type){ //to stack overflow....
        for (QSharedPointer<ModeSession> ms: allModeSessions){
            if (ms->type == m) return ms.dynamicCast<WriteModeSession>();
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

both template methods have

```
In file included from ..\enableIf\logic.cpp:1:0:
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:74: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsReadType(m), Tm>::type){
                                                                          ^
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:74: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:74: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:74: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:35: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::enable_if' without an argument list
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsReadType(m), Tm>::type){
                                   ^
..\enableIf\logic.h:35:44: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsReadType(m), Tm>::type){
                                            ^
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:75: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsWriteType(m), Tm>::type){ //to stack overflow....
                                                                           ^
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:75: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:75: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:75: error: template argument 1 is invalid
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:35: error: invalid use of template-name 'std::enable_if' without an argument list
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsWriteType(m), Tm>::type){ //to stack overflow....
                                   ^
..\enableIf\logic.h:42:44: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token
         getMs(Tm m, typename std::enable_if<states::modeIsWriteType(m), Tm>::type){ //to stack overflow....
```

I am not sure if I am doing right, trying to put my constexpr function inside , but there should be bool argument as I understand, and examples I follow have std::base_of or std::is_integer that use bool as return, so what's the difference?

I might consider another approaches, but the point is, that I need to care the sessions that have some common methods and unique for each type; 
(Maybe taking out those methods to implement it in different new sessionManager class)

Comment: please, it sounds like an interesting question but this doesn't need `qt`. Make it a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show full unedited exact compiler messages, not your own rendition.

Comment: I added whole compiler messages, and the project is on qt that requires c++14, so I'll keep it like that

Comment: From the code it seems that this `states::modeIsWriteType(m)` is actually a runtime functionality, which then is not suitable for template calculation.

Comment: You are trying to use something that is not a constant expression as a non-type template argument. `m` is not a constant expression, so neither are `modeIsReadType(m)` nor `modeIsWriteType(m)`.

Comment: oh I get it! still got to think how to make it right,